# How to set a div height according to another div height using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 divs. Since div 1 could be longer, i.e. infinite scroll div, I want to make div 2 the same height with div 1 using javascript. I tried to use the code below, but it does not work. Why?

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("div2").setAttribute("height",document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight);
</script>
```

my divs:

```
#div1 {
width: 700px;
background: #FFF;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}

#div2 {
width: 300px;
background-image: url(../images/user_panel.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: you should wait for the dom to be ready before getting any element heights

Comment: Depending on how your html looks like you could do this in css alone.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
div2.style.height = div1.style.height; // Might have to add +"px" here.
```

Just from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

the `setAttribute` function is a DOM function to add a new attribute to an HTML element. You are trying to add the `height` on a div. That would have the effect:

```
<div id="div2" height="...">...</div>
```

But HTML does not define such an `height` HTML element attribute.

What you are looking for is to set the **style** of the DOM element. That would be the `style` DOM element property. And inside the `style` you have the `height` property that you must set:

```
document.getElementById("div2").style.height = document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight + "px";
```

In the above code sample you might also think about `div1`'s padding (probably bringing it into the computation). This is because `clientHeight` includes the padding but `style.height` does not.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("div2").style.height=document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight+'px';
```